# Audio/Video drift when streaming to Twitch using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspivid

I'm trying to build a Twitch streaming box to stream from an input device.
 Link to the project is:

https://github.com/jimbobbennett/RaspberryPiTwitchStreamer

My setup is:

- Raspberry Pi Model 3B+
- [Auvidea B101 HDMI to CSI-2 bridge](https://auvidea.eu/b101-hdmi-to-csi-2-bridge-15-pin-fpc/)
- USB sound card
- Raspbian

I'm taking an HDMI feed from a Surface book into the HDMI - CSI-2 bridge, and connected the headphone jack of the surface to the USB sound card.

I bring the video in using `raspivid` and mix in the audio via `ALSA` and combine it all and stream using `FFmpeg`.

My problem is the audio and video are out of sync, and seem to drift. The audio is out by about 15-20 seconds at the start, and the video is streaming at a slower speed that the input. The stream starts about 15 seconds out, and seems to play at about three quarters speed, so after a couple of minutes it is half a minute out.

My FFmpeg command is:

```sh
raspivid -n -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -g 50 -b 250000 -o - | 
  ffmpeg -r 25.37 -thread_queue_size 512 -i - -f alsa -ar 22050 -ac 1 
  -itsoffset 15.0 -thread_queue_size 512 -i hw:1,0 -c:v copy -r 25 
  -vsync 1 -c:a mp3 -f flv <stream key>
```

I've experimented with `-re` `-use_wallclock_timestamps 1` and other things to try to get a timestamp in the raspivid feed, but all with no luck.

I've also verified the same happens when saving to a file, so its not a Twitch thing.

How can I get the video to stream at the right speed?